# Getting Exception while launching Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

i am trying to learn **Fragments Communication** in **Android**.

For that i have written a sample application by following a tutorial.

Now,while launching my sample fragment i am getting exception as shown below.

I am attaching my total java code also below the exception.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

```
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragment_flexibleui/com.example.fragment_flexibleui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at com.example.fragment_flexibleui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     ... 11 more
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.fragment_flexibleui.FragmentA did not create a view.
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4687)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
05-14 16:10:04.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1361):     ... 21 more
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Communicator{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void respond(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentB f2 = (FragmentB) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2);
        f2.changeData(i);       

    }


}
```

**FragmentA.java**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener{

ListView lv;
Communicator communicator;

public View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle bundle)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    return view;

}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    communicator = (Communicator)getActivity();
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    lv = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.titles, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int index, long arg3) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    communicator.respond(index);
}

}
```

**FragmentB.java**

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment{

TextView textview;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    textview = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);        
}
public void changeData(int i)
{
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] descrStrings = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);
    textview.setText(descrStrings[i]);
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:background="#F00">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.example.fragment_flexibleui.FragmentA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:name="com.example.fragment_flexibleui.FragmentB"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
```

for this

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, null);
```

Check if this cast is working, because I have my doubts about that.

```
communicator = (Communicator)getActivity();
```

New Edit:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment{
TextView textview;
View view; // change this
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);//change this

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    textview = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);//Change this
}
public void changeData(int i)
{
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] descrStrings = res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);
    textview.setText(descrStrings[i]);
}
```

}

New Edit :

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {//version support 4

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        replaceFragment(new FragmentA());
    }

    private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction frgTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        frgTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
        frgTransaction.commit();
    }
}


//Your main XML

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
android:background="#F00">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: tried with your first input but no use. Still it is crashing... `05-14 17:16:04.244: E/AndroidRuntime(1031): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragment_flexibleui/com.example.fragment_flexibleui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment`

Comment: Ok, I checked again you can't do that with the fragments because you are implementing static fragments in your layout. Check again my answer.